# Is there a way to redirect the java console in Eclipse to a serial port?

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal, serial-port

I wrote a small program in Java and want to redirect the output to a serial port in order to connect the computer I'm running the Java code on, to a serial dump terminal and to be able to interact with the program entirely from the terminal screen!(the terminal will use vt100 emulation ,baud rates, parities ,eg)

What i have found so far is the opposite of what i m asking ,e.g plugins that allow the IDE to connect to another device with a serial connection making the IDE act as the serial terminal.

I use the Eclipse IDE, so are there any settings or plugins for Eclipse to allow me to do what i want?

Comment: You could call your program in the cmd and call: `java <your.program> > <your COMPort>`.  so your call could be: `java program > COM1`. You might also need to compile the program first using javac